# Scheduling/Processor time for user level threads

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, pthreads, scheduling

I would like to evaluate the following design. I will be implementing my solution in linux.

Having process with 4 threads running ( apart from the main thread ) Vs Having 4 different process.

Memory is not a concern as each of the threads would allocate memory from shared memory.

My concern is in terms of CPU scheduling. If I create 4 user level threads using pthreads library then each user level thread has a kernel level thread associated with it ? Or the kernel see each process as a scheduling unit ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kernel sees each thread as a scheduling unit on every modern Linux system. This was true even under LinuxThreads, the first popular Linux POSIX threads implementation which became standard in 2004 or so.

Comment: So, for each pthread we create a kernel level thread is created ?

Comment: Yes. We usually call them "KSE"s, Kernel Scheduling Entities -- things that are scheduled by the kernel. There is one for each POSIX thread an application creates.